# Losing data while extracting column's content from data frame in R

Tags: r

I notice one interesting thing while extracting specific data from my data frame.

When using the following command:

```
new1 <- total[total$PitchAccent=="H%",]
```

I get 12 occurrences of `"H%"`.

However, when using:

```
new2 <- total[total$PitchAccent== c("H%", "L%"),]
```

I get again 12 occurences of both `"H%"` and `"L%"`, 8 and 4 accordingly.

That is I somehow lose 4 more occurrences of `"H%"`.

How is that possible?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`. You are not doing what you think.

Comment: `total[total$PitchAccent%in%c("H%", "L%"),]` is what you need

Comment: You could investigate what's going wrong by running `total$PitchAccent== c("H%", "L%")` in isolation and looking at the series of TRUE/FALSE you get. The short answer is that you want `%in%` here not `==`.